# JQuery dialog closing on 'x' the same way as Cancel

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

```
$("#termSheetPrinted").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            height: 800,
            width: 950,
            position: 'center',
            title: 'Term Sheet',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Print": function () {
                    $("#termSheetPrinted").jqprint();
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $("#termSheetPrinted").html('');
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

This dialog appears with an 'x' on top of the window to close it. I want the `$(this).dialog("close");` to run when this 'x' is clicked just as the 'Cancel' button does.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to specifically change what happens when the "x" is clicked, but you can create "[close](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-close)" or "[beforeClose](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-beforeClose)" event handlers to ensure that the stuff you need to happen when the dialog is closed, happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a separate function that's called on the Cancel button click and the beforeClose event.  (See JacobM's links above to the close and beforeClose events.)

Here's a super-simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReERV/) I put together to show how to do this and the impact if you call the function from both the cancel button click and the beforeClose event (and the order that they fire).  Ideally, you'd just have `$(this).dialog("close");` in your Cancel button function and move `$("#termSheetPrinted").html('')` call to your extracted function.

Answer (score 0):

A little more explanation to the accepted answer(for all us that need a little more help ;-) ):

say you want to set focus in a field identified by it's id when the user presses the [x]:

```
...
$("#myDivId").dialog({
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "cssClass",
    close: function() {
            $("#focusFieldId").focus();              
    }   
  });
...
```

see: https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.24/docs/dialog.html#event-close